# Whats the difference between 客户反馈 vs 客户评论 vs 用户评论?

Tags: translation, word-choice, difference, phrase

Trying to say "customer reviews" in Mandarin but don't know what the correct term is for online course student/user reviews. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

For online courses, student/user reviews are 用户评价 or 用户评论.
反馈 is feedback, and 客户 sounds like some business service buyers.

Answer (score 1):

客户评价 = "customer evaluation"

客戶评论 = "customer comments"

用(user)戶(account) - "account user" is very close, and interchangeable, to 客戶 - "account holder/customer".